# Savage Worlds: Lasers, Reflective Vests, and Armor Piercing

Tags: savage-worlds, science-fiction

Are Reflective Vests the only defense against lasers? If they are not, what would you suggest the AP value of a laser gun is?

Answer (score 4):

Lasers aren't armour piercing and other armours than the Reflective Vest work normally against them.

The point of the Reflective Vest is that it is a cheap, non-military (i.e., not black market) armour that is super-effective (+10A) against laser weapons. Since it gives +0A against everything else though, it's only a meaningful piece of armour in settings where laser weapons are common enough to make it a useful choice.

Answer (score 1):

Like many things in Savage Worlds, this is very setting-dependent.  While the Laser Pistol in the Savage Worlds Deluxe core rules does 1-3d6 with no AP[1], the Hellfire Laser Pistol in the Interface Zero (version 1) rules does 3d8 with AP 5.  If I were to create a Classic Traveller setting, then I would at least seriously consider having lasers completely ignore all armor except Reflec and Ablat.

[1] IMO, the laser stats in SWD core are balanced for a very-near-future setting, not for a sci-fi setting in which lasers are meant to be viable as standard combat weaponry.  If you're asking this question, I would suggest that you consider coming up with your own energy weapon stats rather than using those in SWD core.